# Invalid authentication for YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying the YouTube Data API to get the video list using `playlistItems.list`, using the code provided at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID ='REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET ='REPLACE_ME';
```

I ran this part with the information of the OAuth 2.0 Client ID I created.

My result is:

> A service error occurred: {"error": {"code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google .com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [{"message": "Invalid Credentials", "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "location ": "Authorization", "locationType": "header"} ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"}}

Continues.
How can you achieve good results?

Comment: If you want to iist the items of a playlist, you need not be authorized/authenticated through OAuth 2. Suffices to have a valid API key that you pass to the respective endpoint as the [`key`](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters#definitions) request parameter.

Comment: If you really want to issue API calls using OAuth 2, I strongly recommend to use Google's [Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) instead.